# Teradata session abort AMP CPU threshold

Tags: sql, ssis, ssas, teradata

I have an SSIS package that is refreshing SSAS cube partitions. Each partition is a SQL query running against Teradata. I am using "NET data provider for Teradata" in the SSIS package. The SSAS cube is using "Teradata.Client.Provider". Any particular query executes just fine. However, after 5-10 iterations, I get a SESSION ABORT. After some investigation I found out that all queries are using in the same session:

```
sel * from DBC.DBQLogTbl where sessionid = 123456
```

This query returns multiple rows with queries from the loop. Each query by itself does not exceed the CPU AMP threshold, however combined AMP usage exceeds the threshold.
I have configured the connection strings in SSIS and SSAS as following:

- SSAS: Connection Timeout=180;Authentication Mechanism=LDAP;Response Buffer Size=64000;User Id=***;Data Source=my.production.server;Persist Security Info=True;Session Character Set=UTF16;Connection Pooling=False;Connection Pooling Timeout=15;Command Timeout=900
- SSIS: Data Source=my.production.server;User Id=***;Authentication Mechanism=LDAP;Persist Security Info=True;Session Character Set=UTF16;Connection Pooling=False;

I have disabled parallel execution on the cube. I have disabled the connection pooling as you can see from the connection string. I have set "Maximum number of connections" to 1 on the cube.

Any ideas on how I can force each query to have its own session on Teradata?

**Update**

After some investigation, I am pretty sure there is a bug hidden somewhere in the cube or database driver. The cube just ignores the

> Connection Pooling=false;

parameter and executes each SQL command in the same session. So I've looked into how the driver handles pooling. According to the documentation, the connection string is used as a key when storing a connection resource in the pool. Therefore if you supply a different connection string the driver handles such case as "new connection" and does not use the one already existing in the pool. Now I have a script task after each iteration that "shuffles" the parameters of a given connection string and updates the connection on the cube. This is definitely a hack and I do not recommend this as a solution but desperate times call for desperate measures...

```
string dcs = @"Connection Timeout=180;Authentication Mechanism=LDAP;Response Buffer Size=64000;User Id=***;Data Source=my.production.server;Persist Security Info=True;Session Character Set=UTF16;Connection Pooling=False;Connection Pooling Timeout=15;Command Timeout=900";
Random r = new Random();
var shuffled = dcs.Split(';').OrderBy(x => r.Next()).ToArray();
var newCs = string.Join(";", shuffled);
```

Comment: Enforcing a limit on total session CPU is unusual; typically such limits are applied to individual requests. But maybe have a talk with your DBA team to see if they are willing to make allowance for the current cube refresh behavior. If not,  you may need separate jobs / packages to force separate sessions.

Comment: And for the question as initially posed (How to force separate sessions), you may want to add SSAS and/or SSIS tags. That's really not a Teradata or a SQL language question.